# como abrir apenas um campo

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Eu estou com o seguinte problema ao pedir para o jquery abrir o formulário ele acaba abrindo todos de uma vez para enviar uma resposta no comentário, mas preciso que ele abra apenas o que clickei como faço isso. Segue os codigos.

javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.resposta').click(function(){
       var id = $(this).children('input').val();
       var resposta = $('.restposta').id;

    $('.resposta').fadeOut("fast");
    $('.resp').fadeIn("fast");

    });
    return false;
});
```

Php que pega os dados do banco

```
 <?php 
                   /*
                 **********************************************
                 **********************************************
                 ***********Função para exibição dos***********
                 ****************comentarios*******************
                 **********************************************/

                    $comentar = new Read;
              $comentar ->ExeRead('coment', 'WHERE video = :video ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 4', "video={$sei[1]}");
              foreach ($comentar->getResult() as $big):
                  extract($big);
              $image = new Read;
              $image ->ExeRead('users', 'WHERE id = :id', "id={$big['user']}");
              foreach ($image->getResult() as $imx)
                  extract ($imx);
            /*
                 **********************************************
                 **********************************************
                 *********Fim da função de exibição************
                 ***************de comentarios*****************
                 **********************************************/
              echo "<input type='text' hidden='hidden' value='{$link}' id='link'>";
              ?><div class='comentar  fl-left'><div class='coment com' >

                            <?php 

                if($foto == "" || $foto == "uploads/"):
                    echo  "<a href='user?id={$id}'><img class='fl-left' src='".REQUIRE_PATH."/css/boot/icons/thumb.png'></a>";
                else:
                    echo  "<a href='user?id={$id}'><img class='fl-left' src='{$imx['foto']}'></a>";
                endif;
                   echo "<p><small class='fontze1'>Comentado por:</small> {$nome} <small>Em:  </small> {$date} <small>As: </small> {$hora}</p>

                            <p>".nl2br($comentario)."</p><div class='btn btn-green fl-right resposta'>Responder <input type='hidden' value='$big[id]' name='idcoment'></div><div class=' resp' style='display:none'><form method='post'>
                            <textarea></textarea> <input class='btn btn-green' type='submit' value='responder' name='responder'>
                             </form></div></div>";


                endforeach;    

                endforeach;

                endforeach;
```

Edit: Percebi também que ao clicar em mostrar mais os que aparecem na pagina não funcionam a função resposta não abre nada e era para estar abrindo quando clicado ela não executa nenhuma ação

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você deve utilizar o `this`, se não irá aplicar para todos os `resposta`, da mesma forma que você foi capaz de fazer nas variáveis.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.resposta').on('click', function(){

       var id = $(this).children('input').val();
       var resposta = $('.resposta').id;

       $(this).fadeOut('fast');
       $(this).parents('.coment').find('.resp').fadeIn('fast');

    });

});
```

Se possível adicione o HTML renderizado, isso será muito menos trabalhoso, para o DOM não é necessário informar o PHP, apenas como está o HTML. O seu HTML está assim ao meu ver:

```
<input type='text' hidden='hidden' value='{$link}' id='link'>
<div class='comentar  fl-left'>
  <div class='coment com'>
    <a href='user?id={$id}'><img class='fl-left' src='".REQUIRE_PATH."/css/boot/icons/thumb.png'></a>
    <p><small class='fontze1'>Comentado por:</small> {$nome} <small>Em:  </small> {$date} <small>As: </small> {$hora}</p>
    <p>".nl2br($comentario)."</p>
    <div class='btn btn-green fl-right resposta'>Responder <input type='hidden' value='$big[id]' name='idcoment'></div>
    <div class=' resp' style='display:none'>
      <form method='post'>
        <textarea></textarea> <input class='btn btn-green' type='submit' value='responder' name='responder'>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
```

<sub>*Existe uma `div` que não é fechada!*</sub>

---

### Explicações:

Você tem um `.resposta`, que ao ser clicado faça com que o `.resp` seja mostrado e que o `.resposta` seja removido.

O que o `.resposta` e o `.resp` tem em comum (além do nome)? Simples, ambos pertencem ao `.coment`, portanto você tem **duas maneiras de fazer isso**:

- `$(this).parents('.coment').find('.resp');` encontra o parente do `this` com classe `coment` (que é comum aos dois)  e encontra o elemento com classe de `resp`.
- `$(this).siblings('.resp');` pega o elemento de classe `resp` que está no mesmo nível do `this`.

*Ambos atingem o mesmo objetivo, lembrando que o `$(this)` é o elemento clicado, NESTE CASO.*

---

### Demonstração:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.resposta').on('click', function() {

    var id = $(this).children('input').val();
    var resposta = $('.resposta').id;

    $(this).fadeOut('fast');
    $(this).siblings('.resp').fadeIn('fast');

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='comentar  fl-left'>
  <div class='coment com'>
    <a href='user?id={id}'><img class='fl-left' src=''></a>
    <p><small class='fontze1'>Comentado por:</small> {nome} <small>Em:  </small> {date} <small>As: </small> {hora}</p>
    <p>{comentario}</p>
    <div class='btn btn-green fl-right resposta'><b>Responder</b><input type='hidden' value='{id}' name='idcoment'></div>
    <div class=' resp' style='display:none'>
      <form method='post'>
        <textarea></textarea> <input class='btn btn-green' type='submit' value='responder' name='responder'>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class='comentar  fl-left'>
  <div class='coment com'>
    <a href='user?id={id}'><img class='fl-left' src=''></a>
    <p><small class='fontze1'>Comentado por:</small> {nome} <small>Em:  </small> {date} <small>As: </small> {hora}</p>
    <p>{comentario}</p>
    <div class='btn btn-green fl-right resposta'><b>Responder</b><input type='hidden' value='{id}' name='idcoment'></div>
    <div class=' resp' style='display:none'>
      <form method='post'>
        <textarea></textarea> <input class='btn btn-green' type='submit' value='responder' name='responder'>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: fiz as alterações que você falou também nas partes que estão em echo com php e deixei tudo como html para melhorar o código e deixar mais rápido o carregamento.

fiz a alteração no código javascript que funcionou certo, então toda vez que eu clicar em um elemento colocando this referencio este mesmo elemento assim ele só abre o elemento clicado correto ?